# Контроллер не запускается из консоли

Tags: php, yii2

Код контроллера:

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class CronController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex(){
        echo "Yes.";
        die;
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю из консоли, то выдает ошибку:

> Class 'yii\console\Controller' not found in /var/www/user128850/data/www/undercult.ru/social/console/controllers/CronController.php on line 9

из браузера, как из приложения, все работает ок. Подскажите как запускать контролллер в консоли?

Comment: `Class 'yii\console\Controller' not found in ` говорит о том, что в скрипте консольного запуска не подключается автолоадер. Если используется composer - то это `/vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Я считаю, что ошибка в `namespace`, уточните, где именно находится ваш файл?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас путаница с namespace. Попробуйте переделать по примеру:

```
class ExampleController extends \yii\console\Controller
{
// Команда "yii example/create test" вызовет "actionCreate('test')"
public function actionCreate($name) { ... }

// Команда "yii example/index city" вызовет "actionIndex('city', 'name')"
// Команда "yii example/index city id" вызовет "actionIndex('city', 'id')"
public function actionIndex($category, $order = 'name') { ... }

// Команда "yii example/add test" вызовет "actionAdd(['test'])"
// Команда "yii example/add test1,test2" вызовет "actionAdd(['test1', 'test2'])"
public function actionAdd(array $name) { ... }
}
```